# Health Kit WatchOs 3: How do I record a mindfulSession?

Tags: swift, healthkit, watchos-3

How do I record a mindfulSession while using HKWorkoutSession in watchOS 3? I'm able to ask for mindfulSession permissions both reading and writing but when I use `store.execute(query)` to start the HKWorkoutSession I don't get anything in the **updateHanlder**. The heart rate with HKWorkoutSession works perfectly even in background. but I'm not able to figure out how suppose this to work. `HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.mindfulSession`

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3: Watch OS 3:** Well, I figured it out. `HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.mindfulSession` is used as a category type to save mindfulness sessions to health store. I actually use it on watchOS 3 to store meditations sessions. as the following;

```
// Create Mindfulness category type
let categoryType = HKSampleType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.mindfulSession)

// Now create the sample
let smpleObject = HKCategorySample(type: sampleType!, value: HKCategoryValue.notApplicable.rawValue, start: Date().addingTimeInterval(-10000), end: Date())


// Finally save to health store
store.save(smpleObject) { (result:Bool, error:Error?) in

        if result{

            print("Saved")
        }else{

           print("error saving mindfulSession",error?.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```

Now if you open Health App on the iPhone you should see some data in the mindfulness section.

Comment: please select as correct answer if that worked for you :D

Comment: does your mindful app also record minutes to the Move and Exercise rings? Any idea how to NOT let it do this?